# Ionic 3 navCtrl.setroot()

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In a component (LoginPage) I'm trying to use

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(otherPage)
```

but it keeps throwing

> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Content -> NavController]:
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for NavController!

How can I change the rootpage from a component?

I want to go from LoginPage to HomePage.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { HomePage } from "../../pages/home/home";
import { UserProvider } from "../../providers/user/user";

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({   selector: "page-login",   templateUrl: "login.html" })
    export class LoginPage {   constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private userProv: UserProvider   ) {}

      signInWithFacebook() {
        this.afAuth.auth
          .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
          .then(res => {
            const user = res.user;
            this.userProv.cargarUsuario(
              user.displayName,
              user.email,
              user.photoURL,
              user.uid,
              "facebook"
            );
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
          });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have ion-nav in your login page?

Comment: No I don't have ion-nav in login

Comment: Please check this : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component

Comment: What was wrong is that I had injected navcontroller in a provider that I was calling from HomePage... bad Bug thanks